# How to add "Not for Replication" to identity column in powerdesigner model

Tags: powerdesigner

I am using Power designer version 15.3. I have designed a table in power designer model. In column properties I have checked Identity option for primarykey column.
Now I would like to add "Not for Replication" to this existing primarykey column in powerdesigner model.

What a option do I  choose in power designer model to set a primarykey column to "Not for Replication"  or how do I acheive the following Example SQL-script in power designer model?

**Example SQL-script**

CREATE TABLE HIST (
   H_ID              INT                  IDENTITY NOT FOR REPLICATION
)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PowerDesigner 16.5,
I hope in 15.3 this was already enabled

1. open your identity column properties dialog (in PDM)
2. go to "Microsoft" tab
3. check "Identity value not replicated"